# PSQL: select subquery and group by

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, distinct

I have the following table structure:

```
dev=> \d membership_subscription
                                        Table "public.membership_subscription"
       Column       |           Type           |                              Modifiers                               
--------------------+--------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                 | integer                  | not null default nextval('membership_subscription_id_seq'::regclass)
 membership_id      | bigint                   | not null
 name               | character varying        | not null
 description        | character varying        | 
 price_gross        | integer                  | not null
 price_net          | integer                  | not null
 tax                | double precision         | not null
 priority           | integer                  | not null default 0
 currency_code      | character varying        | not null
 calculated_gross   | integer                  | not null
 calculated_net     | integer                  | not null
 state              | character varying        | 
 reference_date     | timestamp with time zone | not null
 created_at         | timestamp with time zone | not null
 created_by         | json                     | not null
 updated_at         | timestamp with time zone | not null
 updated_by         | json                     | not null
 payment_method_id  | bigint                   | 
 code               | character varying        | 
 bookings_per_month | integer                  | not null default 0
 bookings_per_venue | integer                  | not null default 0
Indexes:
    "membership_subscription_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "membership_id_reference_date_index" UNIQUE, btree (membership_id, reference_date)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "membership_subscription_membership_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (membership_id) REFERENCES membership(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
    "membership_subscription_payment_method_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (payment_method_id) REFERENCES payment_saved_method(id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
```

I want to:

- SELECT membership_id & name
- GROUP BY membership_id
- Get The max reference_date
- Not in ('new', 'discurded')

Notes:
Every membership has 12 subscriptions so i want to select the ones that only not in state ('new', 'discarded') then the max reference_date of them

My try:

```
dev=> SELECT membership_id, name FROM membership_subscription WHERE state NOT IN ('new', 'discurded') GROUP BY membership_id, name, reference_date ORDER BY reference_date DESC;
```

But does not return what expected for me

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH membership_subscription(membership_id,name,state,reference_date) AS ( VALUES
  (1,'name-1','new','2016-03-18'::DATE),
  (1,'name-2','discurded','2016-03-17'::DATE),
  (1,'name-3','state 1','2016-03-16'::DATE), -- record #1 to select 
  (1,'name-4','state 2','2016-03-15'::DATE), 
  (2,'name-5','new','2015-03-15'::DATE),
  (2,'name-6','discurded','2015-03-16'::DATE),
  (2,'name-7','state 3','2015-03-17'::DATE),
  (2,'name-8','state 4','2015-03-18'::DATE) -- record #2 to select
)
SELECT
  DISTINCT ON (membership_id)
  membership_id,
  name,
  max(reference_date)
FROM membership_subscription
WHERE state NOT IN ('new','discurded')
GROUP BY membership_id,name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to include reference_date into grouping, remove it and your query should work. To get the latest reference_date in each group you should use aggregate function max.

The code (I didn't test it):

```
SELECT membership_id, name, max(reference_date) FROM membership_subscription WHERE state NOT IN ('new', 'discurded') GROUP BY membership_id, name ORDER BY 3 DESC;
```